# How do I introduce row names to a function in R

Tags: r, user-defined-functions

Hi I have a utility function I've put together to insert rows into a dataframe below. If I was writing out the formula by hand I would put something like

`newframe=rbind(oldframe[1:rownum,],row_to_insert=row_to_insert,oldframe[(rownum+1:nrow(oldframe),]` to name `row_to_insert`. Could someone tell me how to do this in a function?

Thanks

```
insertrows=function (x, y, rownum) 
{
    newframe = rbind(y[1:rownum, ], x, y[(rownum + 1):nrow(y), 
        ])
    return(data.frame(newframe))
}
```

MWE of some underlying data added below

```
financials=data.frame(sales=c(100,150,200,250),some.direct.costs=c(25,30,35,40),other.direct.costs=c(15,25,25,35),indirect.costs=c(40,45,45,50))

oldframe=t(financials)
colnames(oldframe)=make.names(seq(2000,2003,1))

total.direct.costs=oldframe['some.direct.costs',]+oldframe['other.direct.costs',]
newframe=total.direct.costs

n=rownum=3
oldframe=insertrows(total.direct.costs=newframe,oldframe,n)
```

Comment: `df` is the density function for the F distribution. `data.frame` creates a new dataframe.

Comment: Hi @James, sorry I should have corrected that. I don't use the F distribution much so I created a summarized version `df<-function(x) {data.frame(x)}`. I've edited my answer to fix it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this modified function:

```
insertrows <- function (x, oldframe, rownum) 
{
  newframe <- rbind(oldframe, x)
  rownames(newframe) <- c(rownames(oldframe),  deparse(substitute(x)))
  return(newframe[c(seq(n), nrow(oldframe) + 1, seq(n + 1, nrow(oldframe))), ])
}
```

Now, the name of the object which is passed as argument `x` will be used as the rowname of the new row (`deparse(substitute(x))`). The old rownames are kept. Furthermore, the ordering of the rows is now more efficient.

Run the function:

```
insertrows(total.direct.costs, oldframe, 3)
```

The output:

```
                   [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
sales               100  150  200  250
some.direct.costs    25   30   35   40
other.direct.costs   15   25   25   35
total.direct.costs   40   55   60   75
indirect.costs       40   45   45   50
```

Answer (score 2):

To answer your specific question, your function will work if you change:

```
return(data.frame(newframe))
```

to

```
return(newframe)
```

However, a more pertinent question is **why** do you want to do this? A simpler (and better) approach would be to just combine your data frames:

```
 dd = rbind(x, y)
```

then sort on some variable

Comment: hi @csgillespie. I'm trying to automate some reports I need to see regularly. These need to be formatted in a certain way. In this case it is financials and for example, I want an empty row between sales and costs before I do a `print.xtable` on the dataframe. I'm also using it to add rough and ready subtotals without having to manually add a factor column for the groups I'm subtotalling, since its a large dataset. I tried an `insertrows(rhubarb=newrow,oldrows,n)` using just a `return(newframe)` and it gave me an `unused argument` error. Am I missing something?

Comment: We need to see your actual data. What (exactly) are newrow, oldrows, n?

Comment: You need to read up on functions: this `insertrows(newframe,oldframe,n)` works.

Comment: Hi @csgillespie just ran it again. When I run it and run `row.names(oldframe)` I get `c("sales", "some.direct.costs", "other.direct.costs", "x")`, so I'm losing the rowname which is what I'm trying to avoid. Definitely not working on my system. Could this be OS specific?

Comment: You're not losing a row, you're losing a row name (look carefully at the screen). The best solution is not to have rownames. Just put your rownames in their own column.

Comment: ok thanks @csgillespie. I did drop back to using a separate column for the rownames, but that struck me as slightly inelegant and I wanted to avoid it. It sounds like it isn't possible though so I'll mark this up.